# Access to the global variable to modify the value

Tags: c++

I have a c++ program with a global variable such as  `extern double variable`.
I want to change the value of that variable when that is run by another c++ program.
How can i access to that variable by other programs and change the value ?

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
extern double myvariable = 0.0;



int main() {

    //waiting for modify value by another programs
    while (myvariable == 0.0)
    {
    }

    cout << myvariable << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I need to a function in another program to modify the value of the `myvariable`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You want another *program* to modify it?

Comment: I want to relate between two programs by a shared-variable in the memory

Comment: You're probably going to want to make a function to change it, which will be OS specific.

Comment: yes , i want to change the value by another program

Comment: @SaeidMo7: On what operating system?

Comment: If it was possible to do this so easily, that would be a hacker's paradise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [Boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).
You need to create named shared memory in both processes, and store the variable in that space.  This will allow the variable to be accessed by both processes.

In the parent process:

```
  //Construct managed shared memory
  managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

  //Create an object of MyType initialized to {0.0, 0}
  MyType *instance = segment.construct<MyType>
     ("MyType instance")  //name of the object
     (0.0, 0);            //ctor first argument
```

In the child process:

```
  managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");

  std::pair<MyType*, managed_shared_memory::size_type> res;

  //Find the object
  res = segment.find<MyType> ("MyType instance");
  //Length should be 1
  if(res.second != 1) return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the server process:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   try{
      //Create a native windows shared memory object.
      windows_shared_memory shm (create_only, "shared_memory", read_write, 1000);

      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region(shm, read_write);

      //Write all the memory to 1
      std::memset(region.get_address(), 1, 1000);

      //Launch the client process and wait until finishes...
      //...
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Now, before destroying the windows_shared memory object, launch the client process:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   try{
      //Open already created shared memory object.
      windows_shared_memory shm(open_only, "shared_memory", read_only);

      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region (shm, read_only);

      //Check that memory was initialized to 1
      const char *mem = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
         if(*mem++ != 1){
            std::cout << "Error checking memory!" << std::endl;               
            return 1;
         }
      }

      std::cout << "Test successful!" << std::endl;
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      std::cout << "Unexpected exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```